# 10 Big Problems - Condensed Matter

Tags: soft-question, condensed-matter, big-list

I think it was Feynman that suggested that you should always carry ten big problems around in your head, and when you encounter a new method, see whether this new method allows you to make progress on any of your problems. To prevent the answers becoming to unwieldy, I'll restrict the question here to condensed matter  physics (if it proves useful, the same question can be asked for every branch of physics, or even physics in general).

So, what should be considered amongst the biggest outstanding problems in condensed matter physics today?

If possible, please accompany any answer with a short up-to-date technical review of the field.

Comment: Related: [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/great-unsolved-physics-problems](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/great-unsolved-physics-problems)

Comment: I see this as a "lets make a list" question and am close it as such. The floor is open for arguments. Actually the floor is *always* open, but in this case I specifically invite them.

Comment: @dmckee: I really like the question but of course a list does not fit this format. What about community wiki like our reference list of books?

Comment: @Alexander Among my worries about these are that we would then get to do one for particle physics and one for nuclear physics and one for astrophysics and one for cosmology and so on *ad nauseum*. Is there a particular reason that you don't find the one that Nick linked so cover the need?

Comment: @dmckee: I see your point. The link from Nick points to big questions, where a new method alone will most likely not have any impact. I had much more concrete examples in mind, such as the 'hidden order' in high-Tc superconductors, but let's wait for other arguments.

Comment: @Alexander making a question community wiki doesn't change whether it is acceptable. (I agree with dmckee here.) The book recommendation lists are kind of a special exception, for now, but those will probably also get closed at some point.

Comment: @dmckee: I was hoping for precise statements of the type that Alexander suggests (in fact I had high Tc superconductors as an example in mind when asking the question). Also, I'm unsure why it is a problem if there ends up being multiple versions of the question for different subjects - that only seems to imply it's usefulness. Do you have any suggestions about how to reword the question to prevent it contravening policy? I think it is useful, and significantly, that it can only be well answered by a community like this, that has access to an extremely wide range of expertise.

Comment: Well, basically what we are trying to do is avoid accumulating a list of answers without a metric for correctness. So one thing you could do is ask for a review paper listing major open problems in condensed matter, and drop the tags [tag:big-list] and [tag:soft-question] in favor of [tag:reference-request]. Other than that... these list questions are tricky because they can be fine as long as there are _very few_ of them, but where do we set the boundary for "very few"? Perhaps we could work out some special exception for open problems questions as there currently is for book recommendations.

Comment: (cont.) It might be worth asking on meta about this.